# Call to a member function prepare() - Wordpress wpdb, SQL quert

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Trying to run a sql query using wordpress wpdb

```
 global $wpdb;


$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $wpdb->wp_advert_management(`category_id`,`sub_category_id`,`third_level_sub_category_id`,`fourth_level_sub_category_id`,`model_year`, `car_name`, `registration`, `milage`, `fuel_type_id`, `transmision_type_id`, `price`, `location`, `description`, `created_date`, `modified_date`, `created_by`, `created_ip`, `modified_ip`, `user_id`, `is_active`, `phonenumber`)
VALUES ('".$category_id."','".$sub_category_id."','".$third_level_sub_category_id."','".$fourth_level_sub_category_id."','".$model_year."','".$car_name."','".$registration."','".$milage."',
                        '".$fuel_type_id."','".$transmision_type_id."','".$price."','".$location."',
                        '".$description."','".$date."','".$modified_date."','".$created_by."','".$created_ip."','','".$user_id."','".$is_active."','".$phonenumber."')");





  $wpdb->query($sql);
```

The error it returns is  Call to a member function prepare(), seems to be a PDO error?

Do i have to include extra files in wordpress, from the docs that query looked correct

or should i just use wpdb->insert without prepare?

Sorry full error

Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tried this

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert("wp_advert_management", array(
   "category_id" => $category_id,
));
```

same error Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Can someone explain the error? SO i can look at fixing

Comment: the prepare method is not the problem, its the PDO instance, its not inside `$wpdb`

Comment: *...on a non-object*, right? Why are you ignoring half the error message?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `prepare()` method, it's like using `sprintf()`. But first thing first, where are you using this code? I guess you're not using this inside any hook in the `functions.php` file? I'm also not sure `$wpdb->wp_advert_management` will work for you.

Comment: Yeah i think i misunderstand Wordpress and writing to DB, this code is just written into a page template in a theme file, not using it inside a hook. Guessing from your comment that is wrong?

Comment: You have to make sure the template is within WordPress, not just an external file. You can then check for example `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wpdb'] );` to see if the global object is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
global $wpdb;


$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->wp_advert_management." (`category_id`,`sub_category_id`,`third_level_sub_category_id`,`fourth_level_sub_category_id`,`model_year`, `car_name`, `registration`, `milage`, `fuel_type_id`, `transmision_type_id`, `price`, `location`, `description`, `created_date`, `modified_date`, `created_by`, `created_ip`, `modified_ip`, `user_id`, `is_active`, `phonenumber`)
VALUES ('".$category_id."','".$sub_category_id."','".$third_level_sub_category_id."','".$fourth_level_sub_category_id."','".$model_year."','".$car_name."','".$registration."','".$milage."',
                        '".$fuel_type_id."','".$transmision_type_id."','".$price."','".$location."',
                        '".$description."','".$date."','".$modified_date."','".$created_by."','".$created_ip."','','".$user_id."','".$is_active."','".$phonenumber."')");
$wpdb->query($sql);
```